# JQuery Modify So it Toggles

Tags: jquery

I have these functions to show and hide content in a hidden div. How can I make it so I only need to use one button that will open and close?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.pagesplit').click(function() { 
            $('.page-split-wrap').css({'display': 'block'}) 
            $('.page-split-wrap').animate({height: '250px'}, 500);
        });  

        $('.pagemerge').click(function() { 
            $('.page-split-wrap').animate({height: '0px'}, 500, function() { 
                $('.page-split-wrap').css({'display': 'none'}); 
            }); 
        }); 
    }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the deprecated `.toggle()`, you can have your click handlers alternate which function they use like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var showContent = function() { 
        $('.page-split-wrap').css({'display': 'block'}) 
        $('.page-split-wrap').animate({height: '250px'}, 500);
        // Switch handlers
        $('.pagesplit').unbind('click');
        $('.pagesplit').click(hideContent);
    };  

    var hideContent = function() { 
        $('.page-split-wrap').animate({height: '0px'}, 500, function() { 
            $('.page-split-wrap').css({'display': 'none'}); 
        }); 
        // Switch handlers
        $('.pagesplit').unbind('click');
        $('.pagesplit').click(showContent);
    };  

    $('.pagesplit').click(showContent);
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot; I chose to use this method.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event, instead of `.click`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.pagetoggle').toggle(function() { 
        $('.page-split-wrap').css({'display': 'block'}) 
        $('.page-split-wrap').animate({height: '250px'}, 500);
    }, function() { 
        $('.page-split-wrap').animate({height: '0px'}, 500, function() { 
            $('.page-split-wrap').css({'display': 'none'}); 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Rocket, any insight as to what I can do?

Comment: @mchammer: You can "steal" the implementation of `.toggle` from the [jQuery Migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/src/event.js#L51) (a plugin used to warn of deprecated methods in code), or whip up your own plugin to do this.